# How to play video stream in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, video-streaming, vscode-extensions

I tried to play some video stream in my VSCode extension by using flv.js and playease.js, but all failed by returning **[ID:00] video/mp4; codecs="avc1.640028" not supported!**.

After debugging, i found it returns false in VSCode by calling `MediaSource.isTypeSupported("video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.640028\"")`

However, `MediaSource.isTypeSupported("video/mp4; codecs=\"avc1.640028\"")` returns true while in Chrome.

I don't know why, and how can i play video stream in VSCode?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of supported video and audio formats as of v1.72 (from [Release Notes: supported audio and video formats](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_72.md#built-in-preview-for-some-audio-and-video-files):

> We now support previewing some audio and video file format directly
> within VS Code:

[image: > ![Previewing an mp4 in VS Code](images/1_72/video-preview.png)]

> The following audio formats are currently supported.
>
> - Wav
> - Mp3
> - Ogg
> - Flac
>
> While the following video formats can be previewed:
>
> - H.264
> - VP8
>
> For video files, keep in mind that both the video and audio track's
> media formats must be supported. Many `.mp4` files for example use
> `H.264` for video and `AAC` audio. VS Code will be able to play the
> video part of the `mp4`, but since `AAC` audio is not supported there
> won't be any sound. Instead you need to use `mp3` for the audio track.

The image shows `mp4` support, presumably with `mp3` audio embedded.

Comment: how about .webm files?